# `less -R` vs `less -r`: Why do colors only work partially in `-R` mode?

Tags: linux, colors, less

I've been confused by the following behavior of `less` many times:

```sh
# setup some test data
echo -e "foo\nfoo\nfoo" > /tmp/foo
echo -e "bar\nbar\nbar" > /tmp/bar

# now pipe something colored through `less`
diff --color=always /tmp/foo /tmp/bar | less -R
```

The output I'm getting with this looks like this:

[image: broken output]

I.e., there are some colors displayed but they are not fully correct. In contrast `less -r` results in the correct output:

[image: correct output]

The man page explains `-r` vs `-R` in the sense that `-r` displays all control characters whereas `-R` only displays ANSI color escape codes. In `-r` mode, `less` cannot properly keep track of the actual appearance on the screen. Therefore `-R` mode is often recommended as a default via exporting `LESS=R`.

Any ideas why ANSI colors are only partially working in `-R` mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the
[less man-page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html)
description of `-R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS` :

> Color escape sequences
> are only supported when the color is changed within one
> line, not across lines.  In other words, the beginning of
> each line is assumed to be normal (non-colored),
> regardless of any escape sequences in previous lines.

You have multi-line color sequences, so only the first line is colored.

The description of the `-r` parameter doesn't include this warning,
so this option does not assume anything on color sequences and lines.

Comment: Interestingly my version of the less man-page doesn't contain this information (possibly outdated, Ubuntu 18.04, seemingly identical to [this one](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less)), rather suggesting that there is no such limitation. But of course, if this has been added now, it explains everything.